# Does this room exist in the Simpsons' house?

Tags: the-simpsons

I found this [cutaway](http://ajdelong.deviantart.com/art/Simpson-s-House-Cutaway-First-Floor-325012816) of the ground floor of the Simpsons' house:

[image]

But, I don't remember the top right room in any episode. Does it really exist, or is it made for the cutaway?

Comment: Tangentiality, isn't the basement staircase in the wrong place?http://www.redbrick.dcu.ie/~elmer/simpsons/btmpics/bulb.gif

Comment: @MacCooper no; there are two stairways to the basement

Comment: If I had been asked to draw a plan of the Simpson's house prior to seeing this, I would have gotten it hopelessly wrong in so many ways.

Comment: @Shevliaskovic The door next to the grandfather clock looks like it goes to a closet.  Where is the second stairway to the basement?  Is it inside the closet and under the stairs to the second floor?

Comment: The room with the dining table looks very narrow in this picture ...

Answer (score 90, accepted):

This is **the Simpsons' [recreation room](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Simpsons_house#Design)**. It has indeed been rarely used in the series, but has appeared on the show a few times. Here's one of them (from [Lady Bouvier's Lover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lady_Bouvier's_Lover), Season 5, Episode 21):

[image]

And here's another appearance, from [Three Men and a Comic Book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_Men_and_a_Comic_Book) (Season 2, Episode 21):

[image]

The fact that it is rarely seen was parodied in [White Christmas Blues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_Christmas_Blues) (Season 25, Episode 8):

> **Marge:** Well, there's a rec room off the kitchen but sometimes it's there and sometimes it isn't. Our house is very odd that way.

Comment: not sure, but I think that may be the room where they were watching cartoons while being babysat by the babysitter bandit as well.

Answer (score -5):

It is on every episode. After the car eventually gets in to the garage the whole family runs and sits in that room in front of the TV.

Comment: That's the living room. The Simpson family has several TVs. You can see it in the cutaway above on the top *left*.

Comment: It is only that Marge's car pushes Homer through the wall into it. Everybody else takes a different entrance

Comment: @nilon Still the answer does not mention any of your deductions. You might want to add them into the answer or rather post your own answer with the explanations and reasoings from your comment.